# I am trying to pass control to another UIViewController using UIWeb-View login page

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview

I am using this code to set cookie and UIWeb-View for login and I am trying to pass control to another UIViewcontroller if login is success full but control is not pass to another view

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

  NSString *urlString = @"http://streamtvbox.com/site/wp-login.php";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
  [self addCookies:cookies forRequest:request];
  [self.webView loadRequest:request];
  [self Login];

}


(void)addCookies:(NSArray *)cookies forRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{

 if ([cookies count] == 0)
 {
     NSString *cookieHeader = nil;
     AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     NSHTTPCookie *cooki;
     app.cookie = cooki;
     for (cooki in cookies)
     { 
        if (!cookieHeader)
        {

            cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@",[app.cookie name],[app.cookie value]];

        }
        else
        {

            cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@; %@=%@",cookieHeader,[app.cookie name],[app.cookie value]];
         }

}

if (cookieHeader)
{

     [request setValue:cookieHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

}
  } 

}

 -(void)Login

 {

   Service *srv=[[Service alloc]init];

   NSString *str=@"http://streamtvbox.com/site/api/matrix/";
   NSString *method=@"channels";
   NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

   [srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:dict completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)

  {

      if (success) {

               TabBarController *TabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBar"];
               [self.navigationController pushViewController:TabBar animated:YES];

       }
       else
       {
             [self Login1];
       }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View related activities must be done in Main thread. Change your code like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    TabBarController *TabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBar"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TabBar animated:YES];
});
```

Comment: hi I am trying to call that view login is completed in UIWebview so where i do call this method?